# All possible 2d-list index tuples according to some "picking charts"

Tags: list-manipulation

I have $L$ a 2d list, and $P$ a list of lists of $L$ 1d-index.
Lists in $P$ should be seen as "$L$-picking charts".
Let $(p_{i,1},p_{i,2},\dots,p_{i,n})$ be the $i$-th element of $P$, it's meaning will be:

- pick a first object from the $p_{i,1}$-th list in $L$
- pick a second object from the $p_{i,2}$-th list in $L$
- ...
- pick a last object from the $p_{i,n}$-th list in $L$

So for each element in $P$ I want to create all possible tuples of $L$ 2d-index accordingly to the criteria above.
($L$ objects are completely irrelevant, what matters is just their length... But of course, without a bit of context it would have seemed a weird problem)

```
L = {{1,2,3,4,5}, {13,17,19}, {81,-144,0,-6}, {0,1}, {1729}, {4,6,10,16,26}};

picker[P_] := 
  Module[{ranges, picked = {}},
    ranges = MapAt[Length@L[[#]]&, P, {All, All}];
    Do[
      picked = Join[picked, Transpose[{P[[i]], #}]&/@Tuples[ Range/@ranges[[i]] ]]
      , {i, Length@P}];
  picked
  ]

picker[{{3,4},{2,4,4,5}}]
```

> {{{3, 1}, {4, 1}}, {{3, 1}, {4, 2}}, {{3, 2}, {4, 1}}, {{3, 2}, {4, 2}}, {{3, 3}, {4, 1}}, {{3, 3}, {4, 2}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 1}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 2}}, {{2, 1}, {4, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}}, {{2, 2}, {4, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}}, {{2, 2}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}}, {{2, 2}, {4, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}}, {{2, 2}, {4, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}}, {{2, 3}, {4, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}}, {{2, 3}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}}, {{2, 3}, {4, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}}, {{2, 3}, {4, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}}}

The code works, but it seems a bit too sophisticated, is there a more elegant solution?
N.B.: The function should return all the tuples in one common list and not in `Length@P` separated lists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could feel it in my bones that there was a compact way of doing this.

```
picker[pList_] := Tuples@MapIndexed[#2 &, L, {-1}][[#]] & /@ pList // Catenate
```

Comment: Amazing! Here's why I asked, you should definitely try Code Golf! Just a minor hassle: I'd like to have all the tuples in one list, where would you add `Flatten`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad I didn't test your code... It returns the expected number of element, but are not in the requested form

Comment: @DomenicoModica After postfixing `Catenate`, I believe the output is in the desired structure of a list of pairs of pairs as it matches your given output.

Comment: No I mean that the return index themselves are wrong, they are not lists of pairs

Comment: Ok, I've found the error, it should be `MapIndexed[#2 &, L, {2}]` not `...{-1}` because **L** can contain any kind of more deeply nested object, here's why it didn't work with my actual list

Comment: Other two things *1)* **L** may be very large and my picking chart relatively small... It would always be lighter to apply `MapIndexed` directly on `L[[#]]`. *2)* Unfortunately my real problem has another twist to it... I need unordered tuples, maybe I'll write a follow up question once I give it a try

Answer (score 5):

Here is a somewhat more MMA like implementation:

```
picker[d_] := Module[{t},
  Function[x, t = Tuples[Range /@ (Length[L[[#]]] & /@ x)]; 
    Transpose[{x, #}] & /@ t
    ] /@ d
  ]

picker[{{3, 4}, {2, 4, 4, 5}}]
```

Comment: A lot better, thanks, I was unaware on how to nest anonymous function

Comment: I want all the tuple in one same list, should I add `Flatten[#,1]&@(Function[...]/@d)`?

Comment: You could write: `... t = Transpose[{x, #}] & /@ t] /@ d ; Flatten[t, 1] ]`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work

Comment: Sorry, should be: `t = Function[x...] /@ d; Flatten[t, 1]  ]`

Comment: But `t` is the parameter `Transpose` map to, inside `Function[...]`. You can't assign it to either of the two.

Comment: Do not worry. `t` is first used inside Function". However, when "Map" and "Function are done it is used to save the result. "Double use" ):

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both the answers I've come up with the best mix of the two (I suppose...)

```
picker[P_] := Tuples[Function[x, {x, #} & /@ Range@Length@L[[x]]] /@ #] & /@ P // Catenate
```

[Here's](https://tio.run/##dZFRa4MwEMff/RQHQlkhsGofBhuFPGyFgoMwhD2EMDINNkxjphEEyWd30WjXwvaU/yV3v/tfruLmLCpuZMbHUcvsSzQRJR8MHg9w7FRmZK1ojyBtuGp13Qo6uCi0DDZwjyHtdCla@sZVIab4LhGqMGeaUBoytiT1W6fcSQLfIF4b@Gr8yvVJ5aIXOQ1j2CBIEAyxZTPDI9bS/W0pvbbojfn82RD2ZrAz0zNvIbzwgnfpfA5JKRQcINrtEJQV79cQAfmV@vLwYFEAiRMp/yzFNHdeVydlRCEaOkNur4bogrWMucmcYE8BkH8QU/6UY/8C6SsQWUAsCEgjlcHDy3fHS8BuByEly5jhFsFRNq3BqaykKvBzTadX91nO7LrE6dPwsCzftfFLWsXejuMP) a snippet to test them

```
picker1[P_] := Function[x, Transpose[{x, #}] & /@ Tuples[Range /@ (Length[L[[#]]] & /@ x)]] /@ P
picker2[P_] := Tuples@MapIndexed[#2 &, L, {2}][[#]] & /@ P
picker3[P_] := Tuples[Function[x, {x, #} & /@ Range@Length@L[[x]]] /@ #] & /@ P

With[{Llen = 100, lmaxlen = 10, Plen = 10, pmaxlen = 7},
 L = Table[RandomInteger[100, RandomInteger[{1, lmaxlen}]], Llen];
 P = Table[RandomInteger[{1, Llen}, RandomInteger[{1, pmaxlen}]], Plen];
 ]

{Equal @@ (#[P] & /@ #), First@Timing@Do[#[P], {100}] & /@ #} &@{picker1, picker2, picker3}
```

Some results

```
{True, {11.9219, 0.921875, 0.59375}}  
{True, {5.328125, 0.546875, 0.265625}}
{True, {23.1875, 1.46875, 1.21875}}
```